# Emit signals from another working class PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Here is my thread class:

```
import PyQt5

class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):

    mysignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal

    def __init__(self, data):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.session = MyClass(data)

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        self.session.worker()
```

My worker class:

```
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.session = data
        self.status = ''

    def worker(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            self.status = i
            i = i + 1
            time.sleep(1)
```

Is there any way to emit `self.status` from `MyClass` while `worker` is running? Emit it many times? I have researched a lot of information about signals in PyQt5, but I have not found a solution.

Comment: Where do you want to send status?

Comment: I thought that it does not really matter. At least simple print() it.

Comment: But where do you want to print it?

Comment: Define the signal in `MyClass` (which will also need to inherit `QObject`). Then you can do `self.mysignal.emit(i)`. And note that the syntax for defining the signal should be like this: `mysignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to make it without define that signal to MyClass?